# The API version required by this app isn't supported by the Exchange Server version

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I want to implement version overrides in my manifest file, so that I can adjust the functionality available in the Outlook ribbon bar based on what is available in the API.  I believe I need three levels, base functionality, >=1.3 Mailbox Set functionality, and >=1.6 Mailbox Set functionality (due to displayNewMessageForm).

Why is Exchange (in my case Exchange 2016) rejecting the manifest with 'The API version (1.6) required by this app isn't supported by the Exchange Server version that you're connecting to", when 1.6 Mailbox Set is just one possible override?  Outlook 2016 connecting this same server, exposes 1.6 Mailbox Set, so it is supported.  Is it because I'm trying to import the manifest using ECP/OWA (as a user might do)?

I know the [general advice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets) is to test for availability in the javascript, but in my case, I need to suppress / expose a feature in the Outlook ribbon depending on whether the displayNewMessageForm API is available, which means I have to code the VersionOverrides in the manifest (I think...)

Comment: Do you have a sample Manifest? Also what version of exchange 2016 is being used?

Comment: Here is a link: https://messageware-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/p/brianc/Eur-Dr9sdYZFlX7NKy7ISywBh08FYP2DZa63TVQw5cYdMQ?e=vbswZW

The server is Exchange 2016 CU12 v.15.1.1713.5

Comment: Two related issues, not to take away from this discussion.  One: the Outlook 2016 versions we have in our environment definitely supports the displayNewMessageForms command, although it is not listed as a 1.6-compliant here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets .  Thus a concern is that if we are able to put in the manifest VersionOverrides for 1.6, suddenly many clients who can run this command, will not see it.

Comment: Two: we have an Outlook 2013 version for which the 'displayNewMessageForm' appears to be available in the JavaScript, but when called throws a 'Permission Denied'.  We attributed this to the client not supporting the 1.6 Mailbox Set although it seemed the function was available.  In this case we are considering testing the version of Outlook within the JavaScript early to do a graceful failure, since the test of the function does not appear to be reliable in this case.

Comment: There are a few errors in the Manifest. Notably there is no "messageComposeTaskPaneUrl" defined in the 1.0 section. And there are duplicate Resource strings "paneReadSuperTipDescription" in both 1.0 and 1.1. I fixed those up, and were able to get you installed on the LATEST Exchange, and saw it working in Updated Desktop Outlook. But I believe this should work with your Exchange version too. (I am trying to get a version to follow up on this) In the meantime, Could you try the fixes to the Manifest I mentioned and see if it works for you?

Comment: Actually, I've confirmed that this is a bug in those versions of Exchange, and informed the relevant parties. The only workaround right now, is to adjust your manifest to 1.5 so that it will install. Then detect the actual API set version with isSetSupported (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements) However, this won't account for any changes in the manifest (i.e. different ribbon buttons), that you would need for different api sets.

Comment: Our current thinking, as we've only seen the feature not work with Outlook 2013, is to handle this client separately with an early graceful message upon activation.  Deploying a modified manifest is a good alternative, but raising the VersionOverride may make the feature not available to a large number of clients where we've tested that the feature works (like Outlook 16.0.xxxx).  We have to do more testing in this area.